# Can't read MetadataWorkspace for Context which maps to DbView?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm trying to read Mappings from another project, by loading the Assemblies, instantiating the Context Types and getting their MetadataWorkspace through the IObjectContextAdapter.ObjectContext .

My code works for regular contexts just fine, but I have a few contexts which map to Views, not Tables, and every time I try to get the MetadataWorkspace an Exception is thrown : `EntityType 'ExampleEntityMappedToView' has no key defined. Define the key for this Entity Type`.

I looked it up in my code and there's definetly a Primary key defined through `HasKey(t => t.PrimaryKeyId);`. Then again, as far as I can tell Views can not have primary keys in the first place in TSql ?

Is this a known limitation or is there something I need to do in the Mapping to make it valid?

Comment: I don't see why that would fail.  The primary key you define in the model does not have to match what's in the database.  Can you add a minimal repro to your question?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Sorry it took so long to get back to you, I wasn't able to replicate the bug at first in an external project. I think the reason for my orignal problem was the fact that the mappings didn't load correctly for the EntitySet's dependent objects because when I implemented the same thing manually that was my error and I got exactly the same Exception. In my new approach I am creating a DbCompiledModel for each of my mappings (and the mappings on which that mapping depends)  and if I pass that to DbContext() it works.

Comment: I realized that I could easily fix this if I didn't have to Initialize the Database in the DbContext's InternalContext when accessing the ObjectContexts (which is all I need) : I used a modified version of EntityFramework and removed the "InitializeDatabase()" line from InternalContext.Initialize(). Any way I can do this without having to modify EF?